# `lshw -c network` showing drivers that I blacklisted

Tags: drivers, server, realtek, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to get a usb dongle based on an 8192CU chip to work in Ubuntu server.

I've been all over and have done lots of things to try to get this working with wpa_supplicant to no avail.

My latest efforts are focused around updating the drivers.
I've installed the new 8192cu drivers. I have blacklisted the old rtl8192cu drivers. The new 8192cu drivers appear when I run `lsmod` but also shows used by 0. Trying to use wpa_supplicant:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplican/test.conf -d
```

Gets me:

```
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
```

Running without -d

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplican/test.conf
```

Gets me:

```
Association request to the driver failed
```

I've tried nl80211, but the wpa_supplicant results in 'failed to initialize driver interface'. I'm assuming this doesn't work.

If I run `sudo iwlist scan`, I can see the AP I want to associate with.

when I run:

```
lshw -c network
```

the wlan0 interface shows up but in the configuration section, it lists:

```
...driver=rtl8192cu...
```

which is blacklisted.

This seems wrong, and I feel like this is causing me my problems. How do I fix this?

EDIT1:

```
lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by
nouveau               855013  1 
snd_emu10k1x           19556  0 
snd_rawmidi            25426  1 snd_emu10k1x
snd_seq_device         14138  1 snd_rawmidi
ttm                    76326  1 nouveau
snd_ac97_codec        106118  1 snd_emu10k1x
dcdbas                 14099  0 
drm_kms_helper         47459  1 nouveau
snd_pcm                81124  2 snd_emu10k1x,snd_ac97_codec
drm                   240232  3 nouveau,ttm,drm_kms_helper
microcode              18396  0 
snd_timer              28932  1 snd_pcm
snd                    62675  6 snd_emu10k1x,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_device,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm,snd_timer
soundcore              14636  1 snd
ac97_bus               12671  1 snd_ac97_codec
i2c_algo_bit           13317  1 nouveau
snd_page_alloc         14109  2 snd_emu10k1x,snd_pcm
lpc_ich                16993  0 
psmouse                91022  0 
emu10k1_gp             12578  0 
serio_raw              13032  0 
gameport               15089  2 emu10k1_gp
mxm_wmi                12894  1 nouveau
video                  19070  1 nouveau
wmi                    18745  2 nouveau,mxm_wmi
mac_hid                13078  0 
shpchp                 32326  0 
parport_pc             32115  1 
8192cu                502664  0 
ppdev                  12850  0 
lp                     17456  0 
parport                40931  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
hid_generic            12485  0 
usbhid                 46054  0 
hid                    82511  2 hid_generic,usbhid
usb_storage            39720  1 
uas                    17745  0 
e100                   36324  0 
sata_sil               13276  4 
floppy                 60214  0 
raid10                 47818  0 
raid456                65740  0 
async_raid6_recov      12947  1 raid456
async_pq               12960  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
raid6_pq               96919  2 async_raid6_recov,async_pq
async_xor              12739  3 raid456,async_raid6_recov,async_pq
xor                    26091  1 async_xor
async_memcpy           12482  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_tx               13124  5 raid456,async_raid6_recov,async_pq,async_xor,async_memcpy
raid1                  35061  2 
raid0                  17102  0 
multipath              12978  0 
linear                 12767  0
```

.

```
lshw -c network

  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82801DB PRO/100 VE (LOM) Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 8
       bus info: pci@0000:02:08.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 81
       serial: 00:07:e9:da:06:c4
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e100 driverversion=3.5.24-k2-NAPI duplex=half latency=64 link=no maxlatency=56 mingnt=8 multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:20 memory:fe1fe000-fe1fefff ioport:ec80(size=64)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 14:d6:4d:47:13:a7
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

Here are some outputs from wpa_supplicant:

```
wpa_supplicant -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/TESTSSID.conf

Trying to associate with c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 (SSID='TESTSSID' freq=2427 MHz)
Association request to the driver failed
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 reason=0
Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.
Trying to associate with c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 (SSID='TESTSSID' freq=2427 MHz)
Association request to the driver failed
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 reason=0
Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.
Trying to associate with c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 (SSID='TESTSSID' freq=2427 MHz)
Association request to the driver failed
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 reason=0
CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING - signal 2 received
```

.

```
wpa_supplicant -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/TESTSSID.conf -dd

Initializing interface 'wlan0' conf '/etc/wpa_supplicant/TESTSSID.conf' driver 'wext' ctrl_interface 'N/A' bridge 'N/A'
Configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/TESTSSID.conf' -> '/etc/wpa_supplicant/TESTSSID.conf'
Reading configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/TESTSSID.conf'
Line: 1 - start of a new network block
ssid - hexdump_ascii(len=8):
     XX XX 72 XX XX XX XX XX                           TESTSSID        
PSK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
key_mgmt: 0x2
pairwise: 0x8
group: 0x8
proto: 0x1
Priority group 0
   id=0 ssid='TESTSSID'
SIOCGIWRANGE: WE(compiled)=22 WE(source)=16 enc_capa=0xf
  capabilities: key_mgmt 0xf enc 0xf flags 0x0
WEXT: Failed to set bogus BSSID/SSID to disconnect
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=1, operstate=5
Own MAC address: 14:d6:4d:47:13:a7
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_countermeasures
RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver
Setting scan request: 0 sec 100000 usec
WPS: UUID based on MAC address - hexdump(len=16): 0a 0c 18 0e e2 0e 53 35 a2 00 f2 f6 6f a9 25 02
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
Added interface wlan0
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1043 ([UP][RUNNING])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1043 ([UP][RUNNING])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b06 len=8
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
State: DISCONNECTED -> SCANNING
Starting AP scan for wildcard SSID
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 5 seconds
EAPOL: disable timer tick
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b19 len=8
Received 205 bytes of scan results (1 BSSes)
BSS: Start scan result update 1
BSS: Add new id 0 BSSID c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 SSID 'TESTSSID'
New scan results available
Selecting BSS from priority group 0
Try to find WPA-enabled AP
0: c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 ssid='TESTSSID' wpa_ie_len=24 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11
   selected based on WPA IE
   selected WPA AP c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 ssid='TESTSSID'
Trying to associate with c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 (SSID='TESTSSID' freq=2427 MHz)
FT: Stored MDIE and FTIE from (Re)Association Response - hexdump(len=0):
Cancelling scan request
WPA: clearing own WPA/RSN IE
Automatic auth_alg selection: 0x1
WPA: using IEEE 802.11i/D3.0
WPA: Selected cipher suites: group 8 pairwise 8 key_mgmt 2 proto 1
WPA: set AP WPA IE - hexdump(len=26): dd 18 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 0c 00
WPA: clearing AP RSN IE
WPA: using GTK TKIP
WPA: using PTK TKIP
WPA: using KEY_MGMT WPA-PSK
WPA: not using MGMT group cipher
WPA: Set own WPA IE default - hexdump(len=24): dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02
No keys have been configured - skip key clearing
State: SCANNING -> ASSOCIATING
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=5
wpa_driver_wext_associate
wpa_driver_wext_set_drop_unencrypted
wpa_driver_wext_set_psk
Association request to the driver failed
Setting authentication timeout: 5 sec 0 usec
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - EAP fail=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portControl=Auto
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b06 len=8
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b04 len=12
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8c02 len=74
WEXT: Custom wireless event: 'ASSOCINFO(ReqIEs=dd160050f20101000050f20201000050f20201000050f202)'
Association info event
req_ies - hexdump(len=24): dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02
WPA: set own WPA/RSN IE - hexdump(len=24): dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02
FT: Stored MDIE and FTIE from (Re)Association Response - hexdump(len=0):
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b1a len=16
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b15 len=20
Wireless event: new AP: 00:00:00:00:00:00
Disassociation notification
Added BSSID c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 into blacklist
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 reason=0
Disconnect event - remove keys
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
State: ASSOCIATING -> DISCONNECTED
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=5
EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.
Added BSSID 00:00:00:00:00:00 into blacklist
No keys have been configured - skip key clearing
State: DISCONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=5
EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
Setting scan request: 0 sec 0 usec
State: DISCONNECTED -> SCANNING
Starting AP scan for wildcard SSID
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b19 len=8
Received 205 bytes of scan results (1 BSSes)
BSS: Start scan result update 2
New scan results available
Selecting BSS from priority group 0
Try to find WPA-enabled AP
0: c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 ssid='TESTSSID' wpa_ie_len=24 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11
   selected based on WPA IE
   selected WPA AP c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 ssid='TESTSSID'
Trying to associate with c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 (SSID='TESTSSID' freq=2427 MHz)
FT: Stored MDIE and FTIE from (Re)Association Response - hexdump(len=0):
Cancelling scan request
WPA: clearing own WPA/RSN IE
Automatic auth_alg selection: 0x1
WPA: using IEEE 802.11i/D3.0
WPA: Selected cipher suites: group 8 pairwise 8 key_mgmt 2 proto 1
WPA: set AP WPA IE - hexdump(len=26): dd 18 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 0c 00
WPA: clearing AP RSN IE
WPA: using GTK TKIP
WPA: using PTK TKIP
WPA: using KEY_MGMT WPA-PSK
WPA: not using MGMT group cipher
WPA: Set own WPA IE default - hexdump(len=24): dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02
No keys have been configured - skip key clearing
State: SCANNING -> ASSOCIATING
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=5
wpa_driver_wext_associate
wpa_driver_wext_set_drop_unencrypted
wpa_driver_wext_set_psk
Association request to the driver failed
Setting authentication timeout: 5 sec 0 usec
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - EAP fail=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portControl=Auto
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b06 len=8
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b04 len=12
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8c02 len=74
WEXT: Custom wireless event: 'ASSOCINFO(ReqIEs=dd160050f20101000050f20201000050f20201000050f202)'
Association info event
req_ies - hexdump(len=24): dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02
WPA: set own WPA/RSN IE - hexdump(len=24): dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02
FT: Stored MDIE and FTIE from (Re)Association Response - hexdump(len=0):
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b1a len=16
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b15 len=20
Wireless event: new AP: 00:00:00:00:00:00
Disassociation notification
BSSID c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 blacklist count incremented to 2
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 reason=0
Disconnect event - remove keys
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
State: ASSOCIATING -> DISCONNECTED
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=5
EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.
BSSID 00:00:00:00:00:00 blacklist count incremented to 2
No keys have been configured - skip key clearing
State: DISCONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=5
EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
Setting scan request: 0 sec 0 usec
State: DISCONNECTED -> SCANNING
Starting AP scan for wildcard SSID
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b19 len=8
Received 205 bytes of scan results (1 BSSes)
BSS: Start scan result update 3
New scan results available
Selecting BSS from priority group 0
Try to find WPA-enabled AP
0: c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 ssid='TESTSSID' wpa_ie_len=24 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11
   skip - blacklisted
Try to find non-WPA AP
0: c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 ssid='TESTSSID' wpa_ie_len=24 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11
   skip - blacklisted
No APs found - clear blacklist and try again
Removed BSSID 00:00:00:00:00:00 from blacklist (clear)
Removed BSSID c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 from blacklist (clear)
Selecting BSS from priority group 0
Try to find WPA-enabled AP
0: c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 ssid='TESTSSID' wpa_ie_len=24 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11
   selected based on WPA IE
   selected WPA AP c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 ssid='TESTSSID'
Trying to associate with c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 (SSID='TESTSSID' freq=2427 MHz)
FT: Stored MDIE and FTIE from (Re)Association Response - hexdump(len=0):
Cancelling scan request
WPA: clearing own WPA/RSN IE
Automatic auth_alg selection: 0x1
WPA: using IEEE 802.11i/D3.0
WPA: Selected cipher suites: group 8 pairwise 8 key_mgmt 2 proto 1
WPA: set AP WPA IE - hexdump(len=26): dd 18 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 0c 00
WPA: clearing AP RSN IE
WPA: using GTK TKIP
WPA: using PTK TKIP
WPA: using KEY_MGMT WPA-PSK
WPA: not using MGMT group cipher
WPA: Set own WPA IE default - hexdump(len=24): dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02
No keys have been configured - skip key clearing
State: SCANNING -> ASSOCIATING
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=5
wpa_driver_wext_associate
wpa_driver_wext_set_drop_unencrypted
wpa_driver_wext_set_psk
Association request to the driver failed
Setting authentication timeout: 5 sec 0 usec
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - EAP fail=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portControl=Auto
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b06 len=8
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b04 len=12
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8c02 len=74
WEXT: Custom wireless event: 'ASSOCINFO(ReqIEs=dd160050f20101000050f20201000050f20201000050f202)'
Association info event
req_ies - hexdump(len=24): dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02
WPA: set own WPA/RSN IE - hexdump(len=24): dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02
FT: Stored MDIE and FTIE from (Re)Association Response - hexdump(len=0):
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b1a len=16
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b15 len=20
Wireless event: new AP: 00:00:00:00:00:00
Disassociation notification
Added BSSID c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 into blacklist
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 reason=0
Disconnect event - remove keys
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
State: ASSOCIATING -> DISCONNECTED
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=5
EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING - signal 2 received
Removing interface wlan0
No keys have been configured - skip key clearing
State: DISCONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=5
EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
wpa_driver_wext_set_countermeasures
No keys have been configured - skip key clearing
Removed BSSID c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 from blacklist (clear)
BSS: Remove id 0 BSSID c0:c1:c0:45:75:03 SSID 'TESTSSID'
Cancelling scan request
Cancelling authentication timeout
WEXT: Failed to set bogus BSSID/SSID to disconnect
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=0, operstate=6
```

Comment: I added the requested output.

The blacklisted driver does NOT appear after a reboot

Comment: Dang just noticed the DISABLED flag. Investigating.

Comment: DISABLED flag is because Ubuntu server does not enable the wlan0 interface by default on start up. I used sudo ifconfig wlan0 up to start the wlan0 interface and lshw -c network removes the *DISABLED flag.

Comment: Seems to be some sort of weird hardware issue.

The connection I was trying to make was between a 8192CU device (D-Link DWA-121) and a Linksys/Cisco e3000 running DDWRT. I had a spare Netgear router, turned it on, configure the WPA security and wpa_supplicant connected to it with no problems. Duplicated the WPA configuration on the e3000 and ran into the same problems as above. No idea why the 8192 wouldn't authenticate with the e3000 but that seems to be the problem here.